# Проблема с взятием cookie сессии

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookie, requests, instagram

Столкнулся с проблемой взятием cookie сессии с ресурса.Выбивает,что такого ключа нет,хоть записано все правильно.

```
import requests


url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
url_main = url + 'ajax/'
auth = {'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass'}
headers = {'referer': "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"}



with requests.Session() as s:
    req = s.get(url)
    headers['x-csrftoken'] = req.cookies['csrftoken']
    s.post(url_main, data=auth, headers=headers)
    r = s.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/')
    print(auth['username'] in r.text)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\1.py.py", line 13, in <module>
    csrftoken = client.cookies['csrf']
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 327, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 398, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrf', domain=None, path=None"
```

Comment: А почему код в вопросе и у вас, по которому ошибка, отличается? :) У вас строка `csrftoken = client.cookies['csrf']`, такой нет в вопросе

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо за ваш ответ!Не обращайте внимание,просто я только что пробовал изменить данные в надежде на изменение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте указать заголовок `User-Agent`, после указания его, сервер вернул `csrftoken`

Пример:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'

s = requests.Session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0'

rs = s.get(url)
print(rs.headers)
print(rs.cookies['csrftoken'])
```